# Way to dynamically display a div without having it load on the page first?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hubspot

I have a simple code that displays a random div every time, and it works well enough. The problem is that the divs being randomly displayed are HubSpot CTAs, so when the page loads it counts ALL (I currently have 5) of the CTAs as being viewed, when in reality the viewer is only seeing one. So it screws with the analytics reporting.

Is there a way to either stash the HTML in a variable (which normally works fine, but I run into problems with stashing the HubSpot script in the same variable) and randomly display the variables, or store the HTML (HubSpot script included) somewhere else and have it pulled from there and randomly display? My knowledge of JS is very limited so I'm not sure how to go about this.

Example of the HTML

```
        <div class="random_cta">
        <article>
            <img alt="Image Alt Text" src="image link here">
            <div class="text-container">
                <h3>Header Here</h3>
                <p>Description here</p>
                <p><!--HubSpot Call-to-Action Code -->
<img alt="Image Alt Text" class="hs-cta-img" id="hs-cta-img" src="image source" style="border-width:0px;"></a></span> 
                <script charset="utf-8" src="https://js.hscta.net/cta/current.js">
                </script> 
                <script type="text/javascript">
                hbspt.cta.load(000000, '76b59fa5-f6d9-4818-bdb0-f91849b25499', {}); 
                </script></span><!-- end HubSpot Call-to-Action Code --></p>
            </div>
        </article>
    </div>
```

And this is repeated another 4 times down the line.

And this is the JS that displays it randomly:

```
<script>
var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * $('.random_cta').length);
$('.random_cta').hide().eq(random).show();
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have to say, i don't know this HubSpot, but looking at the snippet you provided, it seems you are loading a library 5 times and call `hbspt.cta.load(...)` for each of your elements.

First of all, loading the library only once (in the `<head>` of your document) would be enough. 
And then just call the library method after you called `show()` on the element.

Edit: Since you need a specific key to pass to your library method you could store it as a data-attribute in your html for each of your divs:

```
<div class="random_cta" data-id="76b59fa5-f6d9-4818-bdb0-c1c1c1c1c1c1">...</div>
```

And then get it in your script:

```
var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * $('.random_cta').length);
$('.random_cta').hide().eq(random).show();
var id = $('.random_cta').eq(random).data('id');
hbspt.cta.load(000000, id, {});
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I see, i updated my answer with one possible approach. another one would be to store a list of these ids in your script instead as data attributes.